# Do Jews joining the Chicago SlutWalk march have to be anti-Zionist?

Tags: united-states, politics

Mark Joseph Stern wrote in a *Slate* article,
[This Is a Safe Space. No Jews Allowed](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/faithbased/2017/07/the_chicago_dyke_march_and_chicago_slutwalk_aren_t_anti_zionist_they_re.html#lf_comment=717342690):

> Why are some American progressives embracing overt anti-Semitism?
>
> ...
>
> Are you a Jew in Chicago who’d like to march for LGBTQ rights and gender equality? You’ll have to follow a few rules, helpfully laid out in recent weeks by the Chicago Dyke March and the Chicago SlutWalk.
>
> ...
>
> Second, you must express solidarity with Palestine. Marching in a parade with a pro-Palestinian stance is not sufficient, nor is advocating for a Palestinian state. As an openly Jewish person, you’ll need to satisfy more heightened scrutiny; other marchers may repeatedly demand that you disavow Israel and swear allegiance to the Palestinian cause. You must comply with these demands or else you will be expelled.

There's a tweet from Chicago SlutWalk which I think contradicts that. It states:

> wrong. They were kicked out after a discussion where they made their Zionist beliefs known and refused to back down.

Is that true that Jews who would like to join the  Chicago SlutWalk march for gender equality have to follow such a rule?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63007/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-sakib-arifin-do-jews-joining-the-chicago-slut).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

An official statement from [SlutWalk Chicago](https://mobile.twitter.com/slutwalkchi/status/886846435681087488)  on Twitter is:

[image]

> [Question] will you afford protection to Jewish marchers
>
> [SlutWalkChicago Answer] all participants will be well protected, so ppl making Zionist or any other similarly nationalist, imperialist displays will be ejected

Another official [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/slutwalkchi/status/886368445071319040) is:

> we're v[ery] anti-Zionist

---

For more information see:

[Chicago SlutWalk stands behind Dyke March, bans ‘Zionist displays’ from August protest](http://m.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/jul/21/chicago-slutwalk-stands-behind-dyke-march-bans-zio/)

this article explains that:

> Chicago Dyke March ejected three pro-LGBT, pro-Israel marchers who were reportedly waving flags with the Star of David superimposed over the LGBT rainbow

Then ChicagoSlutWalk tweeted:

> "We still stand behind DykeMarchChi’s decision to remove the Zionist contingent from their event, & we won’t allow Zionist displays at ours"

See also [Chicago gay pride parade expels Star of David flags](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-40407057)

There is video and more information concerning the original ejection at [Chicago woman kicked out of march over Jewish pride flag](http://wgntv.com/2017/06/26/chicago-woman-kicked-out-of-march-over-jewish-pride-flag/):

> They call it the Chicago Dyke March. Organizers say they call it that because they are trying to reclaim a term that has historically been used against people in the LGBTQ community.
>
> The march is separate from the Chicago Pride Parade and is billed as a more inclusive event focused on social justice.
>
> Laurie Grauer says she received her Jewish pride flag from Congregation Or Chadash, where she is a member.
>
> "It was Chicago's first, and for a while only, LGBT congregation," she said.
>
> Grauer says she and two other friends were told they were unwelcome at the 1,500-person march because their flags were offensive and threatening. A small part of the encounter after the march was caught on cell phone video.
>
> "For me, carrying this flag is a celebration of these identities I hold very dear -- being Jewish and being gay,” she said.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63061/discussion-on-answer-by-davephd-do-jews-joining-the-chicago-slutwalk-march-have).

Answer (score 23):

It doesn't seem so (at least not anymore).

The ejection of Jews from the Dyke March for carrying a flag with the Star of David happened and has widely been called antisemitic (see [here](http://www.salon.com/2017/06/26/chicagos-dyke-march-under-fire-for-alleged-anti-semitism/0) or [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/27/opinion/im-glad-the-dyke-march-banned-jewish-stars.html)) and was supported by SlutWalk (see the tweets at the end of my answer). Afterwards, the Dyke March stood by those actions, and used anti-Jewish [slurs](http://www.tabletmag.com/scroll/240785/chicago-dyke-march-drops-pretense-deploys-anti-semitic-term-popularized-by-neo-nazis) created and used by Nazis while defending their actions (which SlutWalk did not support).

It seems that at least the SlutWalk had a change of mind regarding the banning of Jewish or "Zionist" symbols:

> “We are not banning any symbols or any kind of ethnic or heritage flags,” Red said, explaining SlutWalk Chicago's new policy. “Those are welcome, everyone is welcome to express themselves as they see fit at SlutWalk. [...]
>
> Red said on Friday that [the tweets in question] shouldn't have been made. “That came out of a very rash tweet that we sent out, that we are banning Zionist symbols that we should not have sent out, as a result of a particular social media team responding very urgently, without talking to the collective,” they said. [...]
>
> According to Red, SlutWalk has since reached out to the Jewish and Muslim communities in Chicago to show that the event is inclusive and offers a safe space to all participants. [...]
>
> **According to its new policy, SlutWalk Chicago will not only allow participants to display the Star of David, but also won't ban other symbols widely seen as Zionist**.
>
> Asked if someone would be banned from SlutWalk Chicago for bringing an Israeli flag, Red said firmly that they would not be. “No one would be asked to leave," they said.
> <sub>[SlutWalk Chicago to Allow Zionist Symbols After All: 'We Have Some Apologizing to Do'](http://www.haaretz.com/us-news/.premium-1.804026)</sub>

The entire interview in which this new policy was expressed is available [on Gretchen Rachel Hammond's blog](http://www.gretchenrachelhammond.com/six-pints-at-the-old-mill/chicago-slutwalk-organizer-addresses-flag-controversy).

Note that the "rash tweet" were actually multiple tweets over several days, such as [this one](https://twitter.com/slutwalkchi/status/886846435681087488) from the 15th, [this one](https://twitter.com/slutwalkchi/status/886368445071319040) from the 17th, or [this one](https://twitter.com/slutwalkchi/status/888826406506987520) from the 22nd (all about banning "Zionist displays").